# Git - finding the SHA1 of an individual file in the index

Tags: git, sha1

I've added a file to the 'index' with:

```
git add myfile.java
```

How do I find out the SHA1 of this file?

Comment: Just for reference: Kind of [the inverse question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1)

Comment: `git rev-parse :myfile.java`

Comment: @jthill, not sure why this is not an answer on its own.

Comment: @jthill -- this worked perfectly for me. I just wanted to do a git diff of two blobs, and this gave me the sha1 of each blob no problems. (NOTE: you can specify a separate branch with `<branch>:myfile.java`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You want the `-s` option to `git ls-files`. This gives you the mode and sha1 hash of the file in the index.

```
git ls-files -s myfile.java
```

Note that you do not want `git hash-object` as this gives you the sha1 id of the file in the working tree as it currently is, not of the file that you've added to the index. These will be different once you make changes to the working tree copy after the `git add`.

Comment: How to obtain real file SHA1  *from git*, as `sha1sum README.md`?

Answer (score 124):

It's an old question but one thing needs some clarification:

This question and the answers below talk about **the Git hash** of a file which is **not exactly the same as** *"the SHA1 of this file"* as asked in the question.

In short:

If you want to get the **Git hash of the file in index** - see
[the answer by CB Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index#answer-460422):

```
git ls-files -s $file
```

If you want to get the **Git hash of any file on your filesystem** - see
[the answer by cnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index#answer-460315):

```
git hash-object $file
```

If you want to get the **Git hash of any file on your filesystem and you don't have Git installed**:

```
(echo -ne "blob `wc -c < $file`\0"; cat $file) | sha1sum
```

(The above shows how the Git hash is actually computed - it's not the sha1 sum of the file but a sha1 sum of the string **"blob SIZE\0CONTENT"** where **"blob"** is literally a string "blob" (it is followed by a space), **SIZE** is the file size in bytes (an ASCII decimal), **"\0"** is the null character and **CONTENT** is the actual file's content).

If you want to get just **"the SHA1 of this file"** as was literally asked in the question:

```
sha1sum < $file
```

If you don't have `sha1sum` you can use `shasum -a1` or `openssl dgst -sha1` (with a slightly different output format).

Comment: Another question, is there a hash computed on the combined file-and-folders contents of a commit? i.e. two different commits might have the same contents (`git diff` is empty`) merely because the comments, timestamps, or histories are different. Given two git repos on two machines that aren't connected to each other, how would I confirm that two commits actually have the same contents?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Yes, there are blobs, trees and commits. All of them have hashes. Two commits on different machines will likely have same tree root hash, but different commit hash due to different commit time. If the time is the same, then the hashes will be the same.

Comment: wc -c < $file  has a blank at the begining in Mac.  Try this , (echo -ne "blob `stat -f "%z" $file`\0"; cat $file) | shasum

Answer (score 23):

```
$ git hash-object myfile.java
802992c4220de19a90767f3000a79a31b98d0df7
```

Comment: Here's why this answer got rated worse than the one by Charles: this actually gives you the SHA1 of the version of the file that's in the working tree, not of the indexed/staged version. It also has the disadvantage that it needs to recalculate the SHA1 even if it's already stored in the index.

Comment: @JanKrüger Thanks for clarifying that! Very helpful. Now, `git hash-object` is still useful for something, as otherwise one would need to do something like `( perl -e '$size = (-s shift); print "blob $size\x00"' foo.txt && cat foo.txt ) | openssl sha1`. Furthermore, it produces the hash by itself whereas the `ls-files -s` appears to require some `cut`ting to isolate that hash.

Comment: How to request real SHA1?  `git ls-files -s README.md` (=`git hash-object README.md`) **is not `sha1sum README.md`**  in any repository!

Answer (score 0):

Warning: if you need to get that SHA1 on *too many* files, you will get an error, because of a leak fixed with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023):

See [commit 590b636](https://github.com/git/git/commit/590b63673747597ab458cb4414e68bb7c4a66aea) (18 Jan 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 630ae5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/630ae5ee65a4e3ed769af04acfcb1fd9b22b3675), 27 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`hash-object`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/590b63673747597ab458cb4414e68bb7c4a66aea): fix descriptor leak with --literally
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> In `hash_object()`, we open a descriptor for each file to hash (whether we got the filename from the command line or `--stdin-paths`), but never close it.
>
> For the traditional code path, which feeds the result to `index_fd()`, this is OK; it closes the descriptor for us.
>
> But [5ba9a93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ba9a93b39bef057be54ecf7933386a582981625) ("`hash-object`: [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5ba9a93b39bef057be54ecf7933386a582981625/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> `--literally` option", 2014-09-11, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/868440f5466c9b3cb6ea188ede95c0c488db7aff)) added a second code path, which does not close the descriptor.
> There we need to do so ourselves.
>
> You can see the problem in a clone of [git.git](https://github.com/git/git) like this:
>
> ```
> $ git ls-files -s | grep ^100644 | cut -f2 |
>   git hash-object --stdin-paths --literally >/dev/null
> fatal: could not open 'builtin/var.c' for reading: Too many open files
> ```
>
> After this patch, it completes successfully.

With Git 2.39, one of my repositories does show the error:

```bash
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/git/seec2 (main)
$ git ls-files -s | grep ^100644 | cut -f2 | git ls-files -s | grep ^100644 | cut -f2 | \
git hash-object --stdin-paths --literally
fatal: could not open 'data/commits/7f/a3338870d66dd3946c5c3a0bd09dadb798893d' for reading: Too many open files
```