# Git - finding a filename from a SHA1

Tags: git, sha1

I added a file to the index with:

```
git add somefile.txt
```

I then got the SHA1 for this file with:

```
git hash-object somefile.txt
```

I now have a SHA1 and I would like to retrieve the filename of the object in the index using the SHA1.

```
git show 5a5bf28dcd7944991944cc5076c7525439830122
```

This command returns the file contents but not the name of the file.

How do I get the full filename and path back from the SHA1?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/which-commit-has-this-blob)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's no such direct mapping in git as the name of the file is part of the tree object that contains the file, not of the blob object that is the file's contents.

It's not a usual operation to want to retrieve a file name from a SHA1 hash so perhaps you could expand on a real world use case for it?

If you're looking at current files (i.e. the HEAD commit) you can try the following.

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep <SHA1>
```

If you want to find the contents in previous commits you'll need to do something more like this.

```bash
git rev-list <commit-list> | \
xargs -n1 -iX sh -c "git ls-tree -r X | grep <SHA1> && echo X"
```

Comment: If you don't know what to put in for `<commit-list>`, `--all` will search across all branches in the repository.

Comment: My version of `git ls-tree` only accepts 1 revision as argument (git v1.7.4.4). I adapted yours to `for rev in $(git rev-list --all); do git ls-tree -r $rev | grep $SHA; done | uniq`

Comment: @halo: I'm fairly sure everyone's `ls-tree` takes a single revision argument, that's why I used `-n1` with `xargs`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Ah, never knew about the `-n` option. Seems to be very useful. Thanks for the hint! However the command as listed above didn't work for me. Don't know why but luckily solved my problem in the meantime.

Comment: No 2018's news? 9 years and no advance in the [git](https://git-scm.com/docs) official implementation?

Comment: `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep <SHA1>` only works if for the file with the given SHA1 hash NO newer/child commit exists.

Comment: Great just what I needed. If you want a real use case, I just pushed up a branch but git was saying there is a file too big, but I only pushed up a few small files and had no idea what the SHA1 related to. Using your answer I was able to work out which file was too big!

Answer (score 37):

Great one-liner to do this:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep <blob sha1>
```

Comment: It works correctly for two scenarios: (1) all blobs are unique, or (2) you are interested only in the latest blob with matching hash. For example, it omits the second (older) blob in my repository which has the same hash. Still very useful though. Tested with git v2.20.

Comment: This is great. Would you still do this, or is `git describe <sha1>` better now?

Answer (score 9):

The following shell script is heavily based on [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/git-which-commit-has-this-blob) and the answer provided by Aristotle Pagaltzis.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

obj_hash=$1

# go over all trees
git log --pretty=format:'%T %h %s' \
| while read tree commit subject ; do
     git ls-tree -r $tree | grep  "$obj_hash" \
     | while read a b hash filename ; do
        if [ "$hash" == "$obj_hash" ]; then
          f=$filename
          echo $f
          break
        fi
        if $f ; then break; fi
      done
      if $f; then break; fi
done
```

I'm sure someone could beautify this script but it does work.
The idea is to look at all trees commited and search for your specific hash.

Answer (score 4):

`git rev-list <commit-list>` won't include any commits which were for example removed by `rebase -i` and now are referenced only by reflog, so if blob is not found by command above you should check also reflog ie like this:

```bash
git reflog --all | \
cut -d\  -f1 | \
xargs -n1 -iX sh -c "git ls-tree -r X | grep <BLOB_SHA> && echo X"
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Harold's comment on another answer, this command will give you the commit where the file was introduced and the file's path on the commit:

```bash
git describe --always <blob-hash>
```

*Tested on git version 2.30.2.*

Answer (score -1):

Commit the file and note the sha1 hash of the commit object. After that use

```
git ls-tree <commit-sha1>
```

and you will get the names of the files with the hashes.

Check the manual pages for more options.

Comment: That's the commit's SHA, the OP asks about the file's SHA.