# How to delete a blob from a Git repo

Tags: git, version-control

I accidentally added a database dump (over 1 GB) to my repository, pushed it and noticed this few days later.

I used `git filter-branch` to delete the file, expired reflog and ran `git gc` to prune unused objects, but the database dump blob is still in the repository. I used  *[Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/git-which-commit-has-this-blob/223890#223890)*, but I did find any commit which has a reference to the blob. How can I delete this or how do I find out why it didn't get deleted during `git gc`?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892 help? or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big?

Comment: Re *"did find any commit"*: Do you mean *"didn't find any commit"* (the opposite)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which command did you call exactly when running git gc?

Note the manpage of git gc:

> The optional configuration variable gc.pruneExpire controls how old the unreferenced loose objects have to be before they are pruned. The default is "2 weeks ago"

So if your blob is younger than 14 days, you have to call

```
git gc --prune=<date> (for date you also can insert now)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice pruneExpire option and was't aware that git keeps unrefererenced objects for some time. Previously, I did run git gc --prune --aggressive. Now, I did run git reflog --all --expire=now before git gc --prune and it deleted the blob.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `rm .git/objects/path/to/blob`.

I am not sure why `git-gc` didn't delete it.

Comment: When downvoting, can everyone please explain why. It helps everyone reading on a subject to learn why something is less desirable or just plain wrong. :)

Comment: Why is it safe to delete this internal Git data structure?