# Git fatal: pack has bad object at offset X: inflate returned -5

Tags: git, zlib, inflate

Git has given me a lovely christmas gift... I'm trying to `git push` a bunch of commits, like 6 GB.  And I'm getting the following error message:

```
-Counting objects: 525, done.
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (474/474), done.
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 3453162391: inflate returned -5
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to ....git
```

What does this mean and how is it fixed?  From Google I can tell it has something to do with the size of what I'm trying to push.

This happened while it was writing.

Comment: Have you tried pushing with `--no-thin` option?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Could you try and push just a few commits (like HEAD~3) and see if that helps?

Answer (score 8):

Based on your offset, it looks like you're trying to push some really big object (offset 3453162391 =~ >= 3GB), so *zlib* failed on inflating/compressing the object since there was not enough room in the output buffer (error: `Z_BUF_ERROR`).

This could be related to temporary lack of memory, or some buffer limits. Basically it's trying to process as much input as possible using the available output, otherwise it returns `Z_BUF_ERROR`. See: [zlib inflate returning a buffer error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288787/55075).

You should re-try to see if the problem can be reproduced.

If the issue is repeatable, then try to:

- avoid pushing large files into git repository, Git was designed to track the source code files, not very large files (like 6GB),
- increase git message size on your client `http.postBuffer`, e.g.

  ```
  git config http.postBuffer 134217728 # =~ 128MB
  ```
- use some alternative client which can ignore larger blobs, such as [`bfg`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), e.g.

  ```
  java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
  ```
- remove the object which is causing the issue ([`git gc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7201720/55075)?).

Other potential issues could include:

- a git bug, since according to [zlib manual](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html), the [command shouldn't abort on `Z_BUF_ERROR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29174601/55075),
- [old kernel bug](https://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2009/11/msg00050.html) (<= 2.6.32-rc4).

For further readings, check this post: [“pack has bad object” when pushing to remote](https://superuser.com/a/1067472/87805).

---

If you'd like to work with large files with Git, check the followings:

- [GitHub: Announcing Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://blog.github.com/2015-04-08-announcing-git-large-file-storage-lfs/) & [Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://git-lfs.github.com/)
- [Git with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17888604/55075)

Comment: Running just a git gc got it for me, thanks for the answer!