# git clone shows 2 fatal errors

Tags: linux, git, clone

I am trying to complete a challenge on Hackthebox.eu that requires cracking a password.  After some research it looks like using JohnTheRipper program would be best for this.  While trying to setup this program on Kali Linux VM, this is what I get (I'm following a tutorial to set this all up):

```
kali@kali:~/Desktop$ git clone https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper.git
Cloning into 'JohnTheRipper'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 91701, done.
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 702615: inflate returned -5
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I can't get any further than this because I really don't know what I'm doing.  I did try a solution that suggested the code was too big or my internet was too slow and turned off compression but that didn't work either.  Any help is appreciated or a point in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned it without issue:

```
Cloning into 'JohnTheRipper'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 91701, done.
remote: Total 91701 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 91701
Receiving objects: 100% (91701/91701), 114.37 MiB | 1.40 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (71974/71974), done.
Updating files: 100% (1930/1930), done.
```

That means your memory is not enough to accommodate the uncompression steps, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36743707/6309) and in [this page](https://superuser.com/a/1067472/141).
I would first raise the memory allocated to the VM and see if this is enough.

Comment: So, I tried this and still get the same results.  I bumped it up from 2GB to 4GB and there is no change.  I should say that I've made sure that I do in fact have internet connection and can even browse to the git hub site listed.  If RAM isn't what you're talking about here, the VHD is 80 GB.

Comment: @RighteousRanger Strange. What version of Git are you using in that VM?

Answer (score 0):

well i simply [updated git to 2.28.0](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) and this problem is gone. could be something wrong with specific versions like 2.17.1 and such