# git clone error [ error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check) ]

Tags: git, ubuntu, clone, inflate

when i try to download from git but some errors..

my ubuntu os : Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (xenial) on Virtual Box(6.1.10.R138449)

> Virtual Box Assigned Ram(9G)
> Virtual Box Assigned Disk Space(200Gb)
> Intel Core i7 9750H

```
 $> git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/bryanyjs/u-boot-socfpga.git

Cloning into 'u-boot-socfpga'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8387, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8387/8387), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7815/7815), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset 381928: inflate returned -3
fatal: index-pack failed
```

[Error Image @ Ubuntu 16.04.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRjkH.png)

[but i use Window 10 CMD(Command) Works well..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPJKe.png)

anyone who some help??

Virtual Box(Ubuntu Network Speed Test Result)

i Think Enough Internet Speed..

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Korea Telecom (210.113.72.51)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by _0rze (Fukuoka) [541.62 km]: 71.874 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 48.84 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed...............................................................................................
.Upload: 47.17 Mbit/s
```

Answer (score 0):

> error: inflate:

Something could not be compressed/inflated properly take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27653116/14998487).

Comment: i tried   "git config http.postBuffer 134217728 # =~ 128MB " and but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me:

```
% git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/bryanyjs/u-boot-socfpga.git
Cloning into 'u-boot-socfpga'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8387, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8387/8387), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7815/7815), done.
remote: Total 8387 (delta 2183), reused 3697 (delta 422), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (8387/8387), 15.15 MiB | 3.81 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2183/2183), done.
Updating files: 100% (7613/7613), done.
```

So there is no corruption on the github end. There may have been a transmission error, or some other error on your machine. Did you try again? Can you try it on a different machine?