# git, filter-branch on all branches

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I'm using the following sources to expunge some large files and directories from my repository:

http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/

[Why is my git repository so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/1036595#1036595)

`git filter-branch` only seems to work on the current branch - is there a way to apply it to all branches at once?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The solution is simple:

`git filter-branch [options] -- --all`

*Note the four dashes (two sets of double dashes with a space in between) in `-- --all`.*

If you look at the docs for `git-filter-branch`, it says this:

```
git filter-branch [--env-filter <command>] [--tree-filter <command>]
    [--index-filter <command>] [--parent-filter <command>]
    [--msg-filter <command>] [--commit-filter <command>]
    [--tag-name-filter <command>] [--subdirectory-filter <directory>]
    [--prune-empty]
    [--original <namespace>] [-d <directory>] [-f | --force]
    [--] [<rev-list options>…]
```

Reading on, the beginning of the docs say: "Lets you rewrite git revision history by rewriting the branches mentioned in the <rev-list options>, applying custom filters on each revision."

So checking the docs for `rev-list` gives:

> < rev-list options >… Arguments for git rev-list. All positive refs
>   included by these options are rewritten. You may also specify options
>   such as --all, but you must use -- to separate them from the git
>   filter-branch options.

And the docs for `git-rev-list` say:

```
--all
Pretend as if all the refs in refs/ are listed on the command line as <commit>.
```

Comment: just to clarify, normally `filter-branch` is listed with `HEAD` at the end, ` -- --all` replaces `HEAD`

Comment: How do I make it work in PowerShell (Windows)? It keeps erroring out and showing the help message for `filter-branch`. I have tried changing to double quotes as per Paul's answer, but I can't escape double quotes there (see my comments on the answer).

Comment: I resolved the above by using pipes (in the PowerShell function). Basically: `git rev-list --all | git filter-branch [options]` (no rev-list at the end) instead of `git filter-branch [options] -- --all`.

Answer (score 8):

As @ben-lee's answer explains, `--all` is required for rewriting all branches. If you have **tags** in your repo, you'll want to clean all *those*, as well as the branches, in order get the benefits of reduction in size, and that will require an additional [`--tag-name-filter cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023615/438886) incantation.

Although the question specifies using `git filter-branch`, the questioner wants to '*expunge some large files and directories from my repository*', so it's worth mentioning that the **best** tool for doing that is actually **[The BFG Repo Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)**, a simpler, faster alternative to `git filter-branch`. For instance:

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

...removes all blobs bigger than 10MB (that aren't in your *latest* commit), and works on *all* branches & tags in your repo.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: No problem @EoghanM - you might find this demo video interesting - it's a race between git filter-branch and The BFG (running on a Raspberry Pi...) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir4IHzPhJuI

Answer (score 6):

I followed all the instructions for doing this on my Windows box, but I kept getting an error, until I stopped using single quotes and used double quotes instead.

My motivation was that I accidentally checked in my `vagrant` environment. Here's the command to remove the `vagrant` folder from all branches:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf vagrant" -f HEAD --all
```

Just replace `vagrant` with your directory name, and it'll remove this directory from all branches.

Comment: Had this problem. Thank you! Also, if your command contains double quotes (like `' rm -rf "vagrant" '`), escape them using two double quotes (like `" rm -rf ""vagrant"" "`).

Comment: Actually that doesn't work. Sure, that works for PowerShell but `git` simply errors out.

Comment: There's a `git bash` on windows for a reason. Use it, sooner or later using git from cmd will hit you.