# When do you need `--tag-name-filter cat` for `git filter-branch`?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

The man page of `git filter branch` says:

```
use "--tag-name-filter cat" to simply update the tags.
```

Later it even says:

```
use --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

However `--all` should include `--tags`, hence all tags should properly get rewritten.

A small test verifies this:

```
$ git init
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/file
$ git add .
$ git commit -am init
$ git ls-files
dir/file
$ git tag tag
$ git for-each-ref
3006eb0a031e40901122ac8984c85ad533982f8b commit refs/heads/master
3006eb0a031e40901122ac8984c85ad533982f8b commit refs/tags/tag
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dir -- --all
Rewrite 3006eb0a031e40901122ac8984c85ad533982f8b (1/1)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/tags/tag' was rewritten
$ git for-each-ref
8e5f09c93a2fbdb435dbe7019abeb841cb5857b2 commit refs/heads/master
3006eb0a031e40901122ac8984c85ad533982f8b commit refs/original/refs/heads/master
3006eb0a031e40901122ac8984c85ad533982f8b commit refs/original/refs/tags/tag
8e5f09c93a2fbdb435dbe7019abeb841cb5857b2 commit refs/tags/tag
```

Therefore the question:

In which situation do I need `--tag-name-filter cat`?

There is also [Why has git-filter-branch not rewritten tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672907/why-has-git-filter-branch-not-rewritten-tags), but I don't see, how to get into such a situation.

Answer (score 29):

You need '`--tag-name-filter`' for `git filter-branch` any time you want it to actually update/create your *tags* - rather than just create rewritten commits those tags point to. The command you supply the switch is a shell script that gets the *old* tag name as input, and [git-filter-branch uses the command](https://github.com/git/git/blob/932f7e47/git-filter-branch.sh#L424-L472) passed to '`--tag-name-filter`' to work out what you want the new tag name to be.

For instance, if you had a tag called 'work-by-sun' and used '`--tag-name-filter sed s/sun/oracle/`', then instead of updating the tag, a new tag would be created called 'work-by-oracle'.

More normally, if you use '`--tag-name-filter cat`', the command is just `cat`, and the tag name used is the same as the original tag - so the tag is overwritten to point to the *new* commit.

The '`--all`' part of the command-line arguments specifies what refs should get rewritten, but *tags* won't get updated unless you use the `--tag-name-filter` parameter.

If all this seems a bit fiddly, you may want to consider if you can achieve what you want using the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Isn't in the above example the tag `tag` exactly the same a the ref `refs/original/refs/tags/tag`? Even without `--tag-name-filter` the tag `tag` points to the new commit after the filter-branch.