# git filter-branch is not removing my directory

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have an `incubator` directory right at the top of my git repo and I'd like to completely remove it from history. I've tried:

```
git filter-branch --force --tree-filter "rm -rf incubator/" --prune-empty HEAD
```

And:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached -r -f --ignore-unmatch incubator" --prune-empty
```

But none of them worked.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a way I can see what is going on or why this directory is not being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting Git history is a tricky process and `git-filter-branch` doesn't make it easy (see below), so instead use [the BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch`, specifically designed for removing unwanted files from Git history.

Carefully follow the BFG's [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) - the core part is just this:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --delete-folders incubator  my-repo.git
```

Any folder named `incubator` (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be removed from your Git repository's history. You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is typically at least [10-720x](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc#gid=0) faster than running `git-filter-branch`, and generally easier to use.

### ...diagnosing the git filter-branch failure?

Because (as mentioned above) rewriting Git history is a complicated business, there are *lots* of ways it can go wrong, so you might need to add more detail to where you say *"But none of them worked"* in your question. The `git filter-branch` incantation you use looks like it would do *something* - it would delete the `incubator` folder from your master branch - so did it at least do that? Perhaps you wanted it to delete from other branches, in which case you need to add the `--all` flag, or perhaps you wanted it removed from tagged commits as well, which would require `--tag-name-filter cat`. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023615/438886

Plenty more things can go wrong, you're better off using BFG if you can.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*