# git: can't find blob - want to get rid of it from pack

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I've a large blob that I want to get rid of!
I thought I removed the file using this solution:
http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/
(I've used `-- --all` instead of `HEAD` so that files are removed from all branches)

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all &&  
    git gc --aggressive --prune
```

I've looked in the pack folder via this [Why is my git repository so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/1036595#1036595)

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | sort -k3n
... last 4 lines:
bc7ae9801052180b283cd81880753549f0f92587 blob   19464809 749446 305054873
acd5f09a35846bec25ebc324738139e5caabc50f blob   294278199 71381636 39607483
986d152935434b56cf182d8a32e24cb57af75ac3 blob   480385718 108184804 110989119
ba9d1d27ee64154146b37dfaf42ededecea847e1 blob   761172819 27430741 277589990
```

The script `git-find-blob` is taken from [Which commit has this blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/git-which-commit-has-this-blob)

```
$ ./git-find-blob ba9d1d27ee64154146b37dfaf42ededecea847e1
```

But it doesn't find anything.

Any ideas how to get rid of it from my repository?

Comment: Is the output of `git status` empty?  It's possible that the blob has been added to the index, but never committed.

Comment: It might be useful if you also included the output of `git fsck --cache --unreachable $(git for-each-ref --format="%(objectname)")` and the same command without the `--cache`

Comment: Thanks for your continued attention Mark; the blob is listed in both variants of the command as 'unreachable blob'.  There are 7 (other) extra unreachable blobs listed in the variant without the `--cache` flag.

Comment: Is the ref packed? Does it appear in `git show-ref`?

Comment: @MarkLongair thanks! I tried everything to clean 2GB of unreferenced blobs out of my repo, without realising that they were in the index the whole time! (staged for deletion)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `git repack -Ad` to force git to reconstruct your packs, and to unpack any unreachable objects into loose objects. At this point you can use `git gc --prune=now` to discard the unreachable objects.

You should also double-check that you actually expired your reflogs. I believe `git reflog expire --all` will default to 90 days (or 30 for unreachable objects), so you may want to use `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all` instead (this needs to be done before the repack+gc).

Comment: thx, that worked! the reflog expire with unreachable=now AND the gc --prune=now after repacking did the trick. the first one cleared this last reference and the second one got rid of the object itself.

Comment: Great! Worked for me as well. Repo went from 80 MiB to 4.5 MiB.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in your `git gc` invocation, you should use `--prune=now`, since the default is to keep objects which are less than 2 weeks old.

Secondly, the `git-find-blob` command you've used by default only looks in the history of `HEAD` for commits, so if the blob is on another branch then that script will miss it.  Try invoking it as:

```
./git-find-blob ba9d1d27ee64154146b37dfaf42ededecea847e1 --all
```

Comment: I tried `--all` on both the perl and the bash versions of `git-find-blob`, but still no dice. I also tried `--prune=now` on `gc --aggressive` but the blob is still there!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a faster, simpler alternative to `git-filter-branch` designed for removing **large files** from Git repos.

Download [the Java jar](http://rtyley.github.com/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 6 or above) and run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 20M  my-repo.git
```

Any blob over 20M in size (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be *totally removed* from your repository's history. You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is typically 10-50x faster than running `git-filter-branch` and the options are tailored around these two common use-cases:

- Removing **Crazy Big Files**
- Removing **Passwords, Credentials** & other **Private data**

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Answer (score 1):

The blob doesn't appear on the other side of a clean push, so this will be my solution (push to a new location, then clone from that location). Any easier way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue.  Discovered my troublesome blob is referenced by an unreachable tree.  Adding to the `git-find-blob` script:

```
git fsck --full --unreachable | \
while read unreachable obj tree
do
    if [[ ! $obj == "tree" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    if git ls-tree -r $tree | grep -q "$obj_name" ; then
        echo "$unreachable $obj $tree"
    fi
done
```

I was able to remove the blob using BFG Repo-Cleaner but I'd be much happier solving the problem using native git commands.