# git fatal error fatal: unable to read blob object 724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2c3671d7899

Tags: git

I have a fatal git error that I can't resolve when I try and `git merge`:

```
fatal: unable to read blob object 724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2c3671d7899
```

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432912/git-cant-find-blob-want-to-get-rid-of-it-from-pack) but the difference is that they can't find the blob anyway whereas I can:

```
./git-find-blob 724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2c3671d7899
```

yields

```
b937291 foo
c616ee2 bar
46c2720 whatever
e48c437 something
057e1b0 ........
```

where `git-find-blob` was a program on contributed to another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223678/git-which-commit-has-this-blob)

`git-find-blob` finds many commits.

Any ideas how I can fix this?  I'm clueless on this one!

Thanks very much :).

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you that it can't find a source for that blob object on your filesystem, presumably due to filesystem or repository corruption of some kind.

`git-find-blob` is finding *references* to that blob, not the blob itself.

`git fsck` will check your repository, but will probably just report the same error.

`ls -al .git/objects/72/4b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2c3671d7899` to check if it's there at all and if it has messed up permissions, otherwise follow a set of instructions of your choice for recovering from repository corruption; preferably, if everything was pushed, re-`cloning`?

Comment: Re-cloning didn't work.  The blob is from quite a long time ago.  I'll look into repo corruption recovery.