# git fatal: unable to read blob object 88a3d3

Tags: git

I have a fatal error in git.

When I `git pull`, I got `fatal: unable to read blob object 88a3d30...`

I tried `git fsck` or `git fsck --full`, but I got `segmentation fault(core dumped) 25%(64/256)`

I had got `error: object file .git/objects/... is empty` before I got 'unable to read blob' error.

I removed empty files with `rm .git/objects/...`.
I guess I removed '88a3d3' file.
(Last time I got empty error, I fixed such this way.)

How can I fix this error?

---

I've found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364785/git-fatal-error-fatal-unable-to-read-blob-object-724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2), but I couldn't follow it.

I cannot find 88a3d3 in .git/objects. (already removed)
Plus, I use python(Django) and I don't understand what is `./git-find-blob` in the question.
Furthermore, the question was unsolved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git fatal error fatal: unable to read blob object 724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2c3671d7899](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364785/git-fatal-error-fatal-unable-to-read-blob-object-724b6f6b35fd871a84ab1742099de2)

Comment: @RonS it doesn't have a solution

Comment: `git-find-blob` is a script in one of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/223678/1256452 (which mostly assumes a working, not broken, Git repository).

Comment: The fact that `git fsck` crashes suggests one or more of three possibilities: you have a bad installation of Git itself, or you have found a bug in Git, or your computer is producing erroneous results (e.g., is overheating or otherwise failing). If the problem is consistent, the failure, whatever it is, is also consistent, e.g., you might have a failing disk drive or SSD.