# Can I delete my local .git repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

My heroku repo grew to 1.5gb, so the nice fellows at heroku support cleared out the remote heroku repo and suggested I push a fresh copy.

However, the results of du -h .git locally show .git to be 276m. And, predictably, heroku throws an error when I try to push master to it.

So, my question: can I delete my local .git folder, do `git init` and push to heroku? What exactly would that do?

My app's code is pushed to github - my usual workflow is:

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push #to github
git push heroku master
```

Comment: That would kill your commit history.

Comment: But what will that stop me doing? I don't have any collaborators, I have no need to ever rollback to a previous commit. All I care about is that my deployed app remains intact, plus its data.

Comment: You could try "git gc" to compact the .git repository a little bit. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

Comment: Yeah, have gc'd the life out of the the thing, and have also cloned my local repo as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big. No change...

Comment: The rule of thumb is that a slug should be under 15MB for Heroku, with a maximum slug size of 200MB. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the upvoted answer but bear in mind that you can't push a shallow clone. Here's a follow up: [Pushing to github after a shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375070/pushing-to-github-after-a-shallow-clone)

Answer (score 3):

#### Possible Problems

There are two likely reasons your repository could be larger than expected.

1. You have a lot of binary assets in your repository.
2. You have a huge commit history.

#### Possible Solutions

If either of these things are the cause, you have a few options. Consider the following.

1. If your problem is binary assets, move your assets to an external asset store (e.g. Amazon S3 or a remote filesystem). You can then remove them from your history with git-filter-branch followed by git-gc. This will slim down your repository a lot.
2. If your problem is a really large history, make a separate [shallow clone](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) to push to Heroku. For example:

   ```
   git clone --depth 1 my_repo heroku_repo
   ```

Comment: The second one is the best solution. I liked it.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply. The shallow clone idea worked nicely but now I'm pushing to my remote repo I get "fatal: attempt to push into a shallow repository". You can't push to or from a shallow clone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone

Answer (score 0):

Well, you couldn't do that, unless you force a push (which is almost never recommended). This would erase your whole commit history and create a brand new repository.

But if you WANT to erase everything because of space... you can. It's just... strange.

What happens if you only push master?

Comment: Oh, I don't want to be strange. I just want to be able to push this code... Do you mean `git push master` rather than `git push heroku master`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do some [housekeeping](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Comment: Did you try git gc --agressive ?

Comment: I tried - left it overnight, but it couldn't complete the task and timed out.

Comment: Try git gc --agressive again, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Try all of these
git-prune
git-gc --aggressive
git-repack
git-repack -a
git-prune-packed