# Pushing to github after a shallow clone

Tags: git, heroku, github, shallow-clone

I had a massive git repo because of a huge number of commits, so following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235108/can-i-delete-my-local-git-repo) I created a shallow clone. I've made changes to this new local repo, and now I want to push to my origin at Github (and then on to my staging and production remotes on Heroku). Perhaps one day I'll learn to read the documentation:

> The git clone --depth command option says
>
> --depth   Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions.  A shallow repository has a number
>   of limitations  (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor
>   into it)

So... how can I unpick myself from this situation and push my code to Github?

Comment: What's the problem? What did you try?

Comment: For future reference: git now supports pushing from shallow clones (since version 1.9). It will still fail when pushing to an outdated fork that's older than your history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@nschum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375070/pushing-to-github-after-a-shallow-clone#comment49294922_11375070)

> For future reference: git now supports pushing from shallow clones (since version 1.9). It will still fail when pushing to an outdated fork that's older than your history.

(Aside: Unfortunately copy/paste is the [recommended way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers) to promote a comment to an answer)

Comment: `Do I have git 1.9?` Yes, git 1.9 came out in 2014 https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases/tag/Git-1.9.0-preview20140217

Answer (score 19):

Git (since 1.8.3) now has an official way to fetch the full history of a shallow clone:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

From the [git fetch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> `--unshallow`
>
> If the source repository is complete, convert a shallow repository to a complete one, removing all the limitations imposed by shallow repositories.
>
> If the source repository is shallow, fetch as much as possible so that the current repository has the same history as the source repository.

Answer (score 14):

I will not agree with the accepted answer for 2 reasons:

1. There are many reasons to fail and forget a file
2. You lose your commit messages and history

Here are my suggestions:

### Graft point

You should have a $GIT_DIR/.git/shallow file with a graft point. If the history is simple enough, this graft point should allow you to push even though documentation says otherwise.

### Patches

This allows you to keep commit history and etc:

```
git format-patch origin..master
```

Then clone the origin and reapply:

```
git clone origin_path
cp shallow_clone/*.patch deep_clone
cd deep_clone
git am *.patch
```

This time you can push !

```
git push
```

Comment: That is very lame though to copy paste my answer into yours

Comment: In my case, it gave the error "<some-file> does not exist in the index"

Comment: I have also applied this solution to the angular-seed project -hosted in github- which was cloned using --depth=1. When trying to push to a different remote target repo, I got the error "! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)". Using the target repo as origin worked just well.

Comment: `"You should have a $GIT_DIR/.git/shallow file with a graft point." -- How to create that?

Answer (score 12):

If you are working in a shallow clone and the lack of history is causing a problem, you can fetch more history with the `--depth` option.

```
git fetch --depth=20
```

Where 20 is is the amount of commits to fetch. Increase it if that is not enough.

You can also use the `--depth` option with `git pull`.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1) 
If you still have the original repo, just fetch from it before pushing:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Option 2) 
**BEWARE!** this is only recommended for new repos, as this **WILL** result in loss of history, and also is highly prone to conflicts!!

If you've already removed the repository where you fetched from, 
you need to discard all history with.

```
 git filter-branch -- --all
 git push
```

`git filter-branch` : Lets you rewrite Git revision history

`--` : separates filter-branch options from revision options

`--all` : to rewrite all branches and tags

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why this is an answer to the question. Code-only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: ahhh, THANK YOU bro! this is the best answer, no need to mess with origina fetch what i already deleted!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with pushing shallow clone repo to Bitbucket servers and I didn't have an access to old history. Finally, I had found a solution. See a sample script with comments below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fix shallowness
mv .git/shallow .git/info/grafts

git checkout --orphan temp # create temp empty commit
git reset --hard
git commit -m "Init" --allow-empty

# Replace all shallow commits ids with new commit id. I copy-paste all refs from shallow file 
git replace 196cdbdb30e608aae2fd7cbe97cc8c0e6fa66c06 <commit_id_of_empty_init_above>
git replace 4c645849b296aaafc1809a9e1537c0fb305167ad <commit_id_of_empty_init_above>
git replace 50eab8bd8c416c47354331211b1efd8688ad8e97 <commit_id_of_empty_init_above>
git replace 649dc7577b87d1b05dff05bf9adc5e46f6612dfa <commit_id_of_empty_init_above>
git replace 6902148fde7b98ff0d6b6c6ebe929590322c95ff <commit_id_of_empty_init_above>
git remote set-url origin http://<username>:<password>@<example.com:port/repo.git> # reference to a remote repo to push
git push origin 'refs/replace/*' # push replace refs to remote repo first
git push -u origin master # push to master, finally

# Clear some garbage just in case
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all # rewrite history
git push --force origin
git fsck # check that everything is ok
```

Comment: `<GIT_DIR>/info/grafts is deprecated`