# Git push to a new remote after shallow clone

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to do this? I have a few branches and quite a few commits, and I am trying to
`git push - --all origin` but I am getting `shallow update not allowed`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I push from a shallow clone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone)

Comment: 2nd possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375070/pushing-to-github-after-a-shallow-clone

Comment: Seems like solved in recent releases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941889/is-git-clone-depth-1-shallow-clone-more-useful-than-it-makes-out/21217267

Comment: I believe my question is different because I am trying to push to a new remote, and not where I cloned it from.

Comment: @eckes none of those links answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible.

Having a shadow clone means that they oldest commits in your repository are "inverse dangling", i.e. they point to parent commits that you do not have. This makes your data structure invalid since git normally enforces a complete history - it glosses over the problem as you instructed it to make a shallow clone, but still.

You can only push to remotes that already have the commits you are missing.

So, your solution is to unshallow your clone and then push to your new repository. Alternatively, if you want to avoid having all that history in your repos, you can create the new repository from your own upstream (which hopefully is not shallow) without touching your own repository and then push into it.

Comment: But it's possible to clone from a locally stored "shallow clone". So why there's a limitation in what can be pushed on a remote?

Comment: @ceztko, cloning is no problem, that's just like copying whatever you have. It's when you push, and possible meet a situation where there is no common ancestor line for the end result. The duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone has some nice ASCII images for the potential problems in one of the answers.

Comment: I think that question is mentioning about the issue with pushing/pulling to/from full history repository, which is a limitation that was removed, so it's not an exact duplicate question. Here we are talking about something slightly different, which is recreating on the remote a locally stored shallow clone using push, which indeed seems not possible for the reasons you're mentioning, but it also seems a limitation that could be relaxed.

Comment: @ceztko, I agree; I could see "-f" behaviour where you just force it to do what you want to do. I assume the risk was too high for the `git` developers (or just overlooked...).