# How can I push a shallow update? Set receive.shallowUpdate on remote?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a project for which I don't have access to the git repository any more. I want to put it in a new repository (on Bitbucket), but when I try to `git push -u origin --all` I get `! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)` for all branches.

Apparently there is a **receive.shallowUpdate** config option, but how do I set this on the remote side?

Making an unshallow clone isn't an option, as I don't have access to the original repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert shallow clone to full clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/convert-shallow-clone-to-full-clone)

Comment: The answer there is to fetch again using `git fetch --unshallow`, to make a non shallow clone. As I mentioned I don't have access to the repository any more, so that isn't an option.

Comment: Ah, then this should be more like it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381860/1267663

Comment: I tried this, but the _deep_clone_ only seems to have one branch, the last one I pulled from the old repo, and it still gives _shallow update not allowed_

Comment: Hmm, is `deep_clone` a new repo?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error message was introduced in git 1.9.0 with [commit 5dbd767](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5dbd767601812209273ae007a97b7c9305dc6cfd), and its test shows that message when [pushing commits with grafted root](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5dbd767601812209273ae007a97b7c9305dc6cfd#diff-72c8ff10e949c0f160b72f993564e543R60).

If by default the remote side (here BitBucket) has left `receive.shallowUpdate` to its default value (false), you would need to contact its support.

But first, try and see if applying a [`git filter-branch -- --all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909248/6309) is enough to transform your repo into one you can push directly (because there would be no more graft nodes)