# Pushing to Github after a shallow clone is horribly slow

Tags: git, github

I've done a shallow clone of a large repo (`git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:myOrg/myRepo.git`). I can push new changes to the remote but the first push is horribly slow. Subsequent pushes are fine. The command indicates that the first push writes a lot of data to the remote:

```
$ git checkout -b test && \
  touch tmp.txt && \
  git add tmp.txt && \
  git commit -m tmp && \
  git push origin test

Enumerating objects: 164300, done.
Counting objects: 100% (164300/164300), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (93987/93987), done.
Writing objects: 100% (164300/164300), 368.72 MiB | 139.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 164300 (delta 41183), reused 164297 (delta 41182)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (41183/41183), done.
```

This doesn't seem to write anything specific to the local as the size of `.git` is mostly unchanged.

I'm curious to understand what is happening, and if this process can be improved without increasing the size of the local clone significantly.

#### Note

This is different from the situation discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375070/pushing-to-github-after-a-shallow-clone) from 2012 where pushing was just not working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: use `--depth 2`.  Read on for why.

Shallow clones (*can*, but not necessarily *must*) defeat an important optimization.  In your case this happens for the first push, but not for subsequent pushes.  Other defeating cases can occur so other pushes might also be slow.

We start with the fact that Git is really all about commits,<sup>1</sup> which are shaped into a Directed Acyclic Graph.  The graph has vertices or nodes—whichever term you prefer—that are numbered, by commit hash IDs.  Relatively immaterial here, but helpful for concreteness, is the fact that the edges / arcs between the nodes are stored as part of the nodes themselves, rather than being kept separately.  Each node stores the hash IDs of its predecessor nodes.

A repository is, at heart, a database of these commit objects.  A complete—non-shallow—repository has the entire graph, from every root to every tip commit.  A *single-branch* clone potentially drops some part of the graph, but never has any "gaps" in the graph.  For instance, given:

```
           node--node--tip1
          /
root--node
          \
           node--node--tip2
```

we can drop either tip and the nodes on that row, but not the nodes and root on the middle row.  In all of these cases, then, we can—as Git always does—start at the tip and work backwards and eventually arrive at the root.

Now, there are two properties of each node that are important here:

- The *number* is *unique*.  It's a universally unique ID.  *No* node in *any* other Git repository (that we'll meet anyway) can re-use that ID.
- The *data* in the node are strictly read-only.  That includes the outgoing edge links.

What this means is that if we have a *gap-free* repository—one that's either totally complete, or at least as complete as required for the tip commits it contains—on each side of a sender-to-receiver operation, we can have the *sending* repository simply enumerate for us some set of commits, by their numbers.  If we, the receiving repository, lack that commit, we ask the sender to send it and also to tell us the numbers of its parent commit(s).  The sender does that, and we see if we have those commits.  For any that we lack, we ask the sender to send those and also tell us the numbers of their parent commits, and so on.

This means that if *we* have:

```
           node--node--tip1
          /
root--node
          \
           node--node--tip2
```

and *they* have:

```
           node--node--tip1--new
          /
root--node
```

then *they* will announce to use the hash ID of commit `new`.  We don't have that one, so they should add it to a pile of commits to send, and announce to us the hash ID of commit `tip1` as well.  We *do* have `tip1` so we just tell them: *We already have `tip1`: you do not need to send it.*

Here's the optimization: *We just told them about **every commit we have** from `tip1` all the way back to `root`.*  Our *no thanks, we have that one* offer to their reply to *I can send you `tip1`* tells them about not just the one commit and its files, but also every predecessor commit and all of *their* files as well.

**They now know that when they send us commit `new`, they need only send tree and blob ("file") objects that do not appear in predecessor commits.**  Moreover, they can compress these tree and blob objects against tree and blob objects in any *previous* commit, from `tip1` all the way back to `root`.  So the sender can send *far* less data than would otherwise be required to send the entire commit, with its full snapshot of every file.

---

Tree objects and blob objects are primarily found *via* commits.  Annotated tag objects add one small wrinkle to the picture, and having an annotated tag that points directly to a tree or blob adds another, but neither defeats the standard optimization.

---

#### Compare to when the sender is a shallow repository

A *shallow repository* is one in which some commit(s) are marked-up artificially as being root commits.  The commit object actually has the right parent hash IDs, but the Git in which this commit object lives has a file<sup>2</sup> that says: *We don't know anything about the parents of commit `tip1`.  Don't try to look for any: pretend, instead, that `tip1` is a root commit, with no parents.*

This means the sending Git, instead of having:

```
           node--node--tip1
          /
root--node
```

has just:

```
      slightly-mangled-tip1
```

In this repository, we add our new commit:

```
      slightly-mangled-tip1--new
```

and now we have our Git call up their Git and offer it new commits.  First we offer `new`.  They say *I don't have that one, what else can you send?*  We would offer `slightly-mangled-tip1`, but **we can't do that** because when we read it in, we mangle it.  So we say: *Sorry, that's all we have for you.*

They say: *Okay then, send us commit `new`.*

On our end, then, we look at commit `new`.  It has a full snapshot of *every file*.  We don't know if they have *any* of these files.  So we pack up the entire thing and send *all* of it.

They receive it all, unpack it, find that we've duplicated 99% of what they already have, ignore the extra copies, and take the new commit and put it in their repository:

```
           node--node--tip1--new
          /
root--node
          \
           node--node--tip2
```

The next time we run `git push`, we have this:

```
      slightly-mangled-tip1--new--new2
```

We offer them `new2`; they say *I don't have that one, what's its parent* and we say `new` and they say *oh I have that one, don't bother sending it*.  This time, we see that they have almost every file already, and don't bother sending all those tree and blob objects *and* can compress any *new* tree and blob objects based on what's in commit `new`.  (We still can't use the slightly-manged tip1 commit, nor of course any of the missing previous commits, but just being able to eliminate all unchanged files is huge.)

---

<sup>2</sup>Or other mechanism, but currently, it is a file named `.git/shallow`.

---

#### What you can do about this

Given that you intend to run `git push`, you'll get a lot of mileage out of having one un-mangled commit "between" the shallow graft point and a branch tip.  So do your `git clone` with `--depth 2`.  You'll get a slightly bigger client Git repository, but that first `git push` will go much faster.

That is, you'll start with:

```
slightly-mangled-node--tip1
```

on the client.  The first *new* commit will result in:

```
slightly-mangled-node--tip1--new
```

and this time your Git will be able to offer `tip1` to their Git during the first push, which will trigger the optimization.

Comment: @Guig: worth noting: I haven't tested this; it's just some simple applied math. One clone-and-push will tell you if I was right. :-)

Comment: Beautifully articulated!