# How to find out which files take up the most space in git repo?

Tags: git

I need to make the repo smaller. I think I can make it smaller by removing problematic binary files from git history:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch BigFile'
```

And then releasing the objects:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

(Feel free to comment if those commands are wrong.)

The problem: How to identify those big files so that I can asses whether to remove them from git history? Most likely they are not in the working tree anymore - they have been deleted and probably also untracked with:

```
git rm --cached BigFile
```

Answer (score 31):

[twalberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405217/1054322) does the trick.  I wrapped it up in a loop so that you can list files in order by size:

```
while read -r largefile; do
    echo $largefile | awk '{printf "%s %s ", $1, $3 ; system("git rev-list --all --objects | grep " $1 " | cut -d \" \" -f 2-")}'
done <<< "$(git rev-list --all --objects | awk '{print $1}' | git cat-file --batch-check | sort -k3nr | head -n 20)"
```

`head -n 20` restricts the output  to the top 20.  Change as necessary.

Once you've identified the problem files, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17890278/1054322) answer for how to remove them.

Comment: I believe those are bytes

Answer (score 24):

You can find the hash IDs of the largest objects like this:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | awk '{print $1}' | git cat-file --batch-check | sort -k3nr
```

Then, for a particular SHA, you can do this to get the file name:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | grep <SHA>
```

Not sure if there's a more efficient way to do it. If you know for sure that everything is in pack files (not loose objects), `git verify-pack -v` produces output that includes the size, and I seem to remember seeing a script somewhere that would parse that output and match each object back up with the original files.

Answer (score 11):

Couldn't help optimizing MatrixManAtYrService's answer:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | grep blob | sort -k3nr | head -n 20
```

This way `git rev-list` is called only once (and not per object being displayed), and the script is more clear.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how to use `numfmt` go get a human readable size, but this converts it to mb: `git rev-list --all --objects | git cat-file --batch-check='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(objectsize) %(rest)' | sort -k3nr | awk '$3=$3 / 1024 / 1024' | head -n 20`

Comment: thank you, this is much faster than the original answer

Comment: This command only gives the size of the biggest blob. Is there a way to display the summarized size of all versions of the file ?

because e.g. when I file of 10MB only is change once it takes less space than a 2MB file that is changed 200 times in the history

Answer (score 2):

Using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) you can analyze space taken up in the repository.

```
git filter-repo --analyze
```

To see the largest deleted files, see:

```
.git/filter-repo/analysis/path-deleted-sizes.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that will tell you the largest objects, files, or directories in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/45366030#45366030). Without arguments, it'll tell you the size of all objects, sorted by size. You can tell it `--sum` or `--directories` to sum all the objects for each file and print that, or to do the same for all files in each directory. I hope it's useful!