# git count-objects warning: no corresponding .pack:

Tags: git

What does this warning from `git count-objects -v` mean?  Google only gives me the source of git itself.

```
warning: no corresponding .pack: .git/objects/pack/pack-fdd1d6e3161128d4fe4b38849cf0.idx
...  (many lines of the same warning)
count: 4715
size: 37151
in-pack: 426048
packs: 22
size-pack: 656437
prune-packable: 137
garbage: 92
size-garbage: 5893
```

Does it mean those objects can be compressed, as implied by [this answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1036595/192221)

How can I tell whether I should repack or gc my repository (apparently there's a difference between repack and gc)? Is it necessary at all or harmful?

Why does git have so much jargon!

Comment: Does the file `.git/objects/pack/pack-fdd1d6e3161128d4fe4b38849cf0.pack` exist on your system? The message makes it sound like you have a `*.idx` file with no matching `*.pack` file.

Comment: Yes that pack file exists, which is surprising given the warning.

Comment: "Why does git have so much jargon" - because Torvalds

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of a too large pack file.

Before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the code was not prepared to deal with pack `.idx` file that is larger than 4GB.

See [commit 81c4c5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81c4c5cf2e18d2b562639596385e49c3c48677de), [commit 9bb4542](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bb4542b8c1b91189126cf0fc42e2689fc9224c6), [commit 33bbc59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33bbc59fed34848215f8ce1ef71ff26b821ccd12), [commit a9bc372](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9bc372ef8210e60d924ec6c0b46624c6d0a4033), [commit f86f769](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f86f769550ef7fb5162a9cd4be5e2be7981d063b) (13 Nov 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fcf26ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcf26ef53ad91400591c47b854a2a834632d6010), 25 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9bc372ef8210e60d924ec6c0b46624c6d0a4033):use `size_t` to store pack `.idx` byte offsets
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> We sometimes store the offset into a pack `.idx` file as an "unsigned long", but the mmap'd size of a pack `.idx` file can exceed 4GB.
>
> This is sufficient on LP64 systems like Linux, but will be too small on LLP64 systems like Windows, where "unsigned long" is still only 32 bits.
>
> Let's use `size_t,` which is a better type for an offset into a memory buffer.

That impacts [`git fsck`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck)

> ### [`fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33bbc59fed34848215f8ce1ef71ff26b821ccd12): correctly compute checksums on idx files larger than 4GB
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> When checking the trailing checksum hash of a `.idx` file, we pass the whole buffer (minus the trailing hash) into a single call to `the_hash_algo->update_fn()`.
> But we cast it to an "unsigned int".
> This comes from [c4001d92be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4001d92be61766d3494489b15590ca0147ee19d) ("Use `off_t` when we really mean a file offset.", 2007-03-06, Git v1.5.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4001d92be61766d3494489b15590ca0147ee19d)). That commit started storing the `index_size` variable as an `off_t,` but our mozilla-sha1 implementation from the time was limited to a smaller size.
> Presumably the cast was a way of annotating that we expected `.idx` files to be small, and so we didn't need to loop (as we do for arbitrarily-large .pack files). Though as an aside it was still wrong, because the mozilla function actually took a signed int.
>
> These days our hash-update functions are defined to take a `size_t,` so we can pass the whole buffer in directly. The cast is actually causing a buggy truncation!
>
> While we're here, though, let's drop the confusing `off_t` variable in the first place. We're getting the size not from the filesystem anyway, but from `p->index_size,` which is a `size_t`. In fact, we can make the code a bit more readable by dropping our local variable duplicating `p->index_size,` and instead have one that stores the size of the actual index data, minus the trailing hash.'
> (Copied to the clipboard)