# How to display file sizes using milhar separation on this git script?

Tags: git

On the question [Why is my git repository so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big/), is found this script to list the repository big files:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | \
    sed -n $(git rev-list --objects --all | \
    cut -f1 -d' ' | \
    git cat-file --batch-check | \
    grep blob | \
    sort -n -k 3 | \
    tail -n40 | \
    while read hash type size; do 
         echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size/p ";
    done) | \
    sort -n -k1
```

But is outputs the file sizes on a bad readable way as:

```
89076 images/screenshots/properties.png
103472 images/screenshots/signals.png
9434202 video/parasite-intro.avi
```

I would like it to display the sizes within a more reasonable way as:

```
   89.076 KB - images/screenshots/properties.png
  103.472 KB - images/screenshots/signals.png
9,434.202 KB - video/parasite-intro.avi
```

For example, this last one `9,434.202 KB` should mean `9.434 MB` or `0.9434 GB`. But I am not sure whether is the best to use `9.434,202 KB`, i.e., just replacing the comma with the dot and vice-versa.

Initially to do it I could think of generating the whole list and afterwards process it. But I think would already be nice to this while the list is being generated. Therefore would not be possible to predict the `right side` justification, however would already be fine to print the list like this below, without the `right side` justification:

```
89.076 KB - images/screenshots/properties.png
103.472 KB - images/screenshots/signals.png
9,434.202 KB - video/parasite-intro.avi
```

I think the printing is being performed by this line:

```
echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size/p ";
```

However I do not understand how to format the `$size` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to convert the bytes to kibibytes (1024-based kilobytes). Here's an awk hack for that that I stole from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/awk-to-convert-bytes-to-human-number-909214/).

```
size_in_kibibytes=$(echo $size | awk '{ foo = $1 / 1024 ; print foo "KiB" }')
```

In context:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | \
    sed -n $(git rev-list --objects --all | \
    cut -f1 -d' ' | \
    git cat-file --batch-check | \
    grep blob | \
    sort -n -k 3 | \
    tail -n40 | \
    while read hash type size; do
         size_in_kibibytes=$(echo $size | awk '{ foo = $1 / 1024 ; print foo "KiB" }')
         echo -n "-e s/$hash/$size_in_kibibytes/p ";
    done) | \
    sort -n -k1
```

I'm sure you could layer other hacks on top of that one to add commas, add a space before the KiB, play with the justification, etc. Hopefully this gets you started.