# Git repo still huge after large files removed from repository history

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I have a codebase that (until now) used git to store its dependencies. The repository itself [is available here](https://github.com/scalagwt/scalagwt-sample) (warning: it's HUGE). Needless to say, I need to remove the dependencies from the repository history in order to cut it down to a reasonable size.

I started by using [David Underhill's instructions](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) to remove the `lib` directory from the history. Even after doing this, however, the repository is still over 300M. Issuing `git prune` and `git repack` helps, but it's still over 180M.

In an attempt to find any bloated blobs, I issued

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr | head
```

with these results:

> 105526b5d3d398b9989d88c2f9fc2d1dc96a85b8 blob   35685609 33600527 31978828
>   d296935e6ac5f3f58b50c789394c9769116e9c34 blob   35658016 33593241 112485744
>   50636f931180a32764edadd854968a971a083f8a blob   28360290 25897864 233390
>   b9e4dd37428e879a258f297b7f5bcfb9ba869695 blob   13108002 11640713 66661788
>   08d2720b2414aa07ce419b17d5f80c333c7313b7 blob   12551621 11124009 89231035
>   6197a478a461275a0396f20c28487e9ae619a5f9 blob   11975135 11058259 148211988 1 50636f931180a32764edadd854968a971a083f8a
>   549eb0c73776fd0ede27a2fcb03366f76f45a13c blob   9136086 8166649 166451273
>   5bc0a0f04a7004bc16cfab1c091c6b369fb74049 blob   9072616 8270262 80951514
>   741480238a6a6ce612cf089245dd46d6890fba9f blob   8858569 8080252 101294029
>   744226651c55b14c1aa8affb78fba4fdf02b577c blob   7412220 6766404 186825167

This is where I'm stuck.  I can `git show` these blobs and see that they look very much like jar files, but I can't figure out why they're still in the repo.

Various attempts to [find their filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1) failed.

`git repack -a`, `git repack -ad`, and `git repack -Ad` all seem to have no effect.

Comment: `git ls-tree -r --long HEAD | cut -d" " -f4- | sort -r` might help you. Replace HEAD for with every commit in a history and cut largest files (maybe filter out those in lib/) and it should give you a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried running `git gc`? http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

Comment: yep, `git gc --aggressive --prune` in fact.  It's part of David Underhill's script, and I also ran it separately in between various other mis-attempts.

Comment: How about pushing the branches you want from one repo to another clean one.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I had to `git init` a fresh repo, and then `git pull` the branch I wanted.  I didn't know you could pull into a non-clone.

Comment: @Aaron: This probably means that your blobs were necessary for commits that were still in your reflogs, even though they weren't on any branch. (Reflogs by default last 90 days.) Git tries to make sure it doesn't delete anything important. See `git-reflog` and `git-gc` manpages for information on how to override. And yes, you can always pull into an empty repo, since "no history" is always consistent any valid history.

Answer (score 15):

### Use `--prune=now` on git gc

Although you'd successfully written your unwanted objects out of history, it looks like those unwanted objects were not being pruned because they were *too young* to be pruned by default (see the [configuration docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_configuration) on `git gc` for a bit more detail). Using `git gc --prune=now` should handle that, or you could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14728706/438886) for a more nuclear option.

Although that should fix your final problem, an underlying problem was the difficulty of *finding* big blobs in order to remove them using `git filter-branch` - to which I would say:

### ...don't use git filter-branch

`git filter-branch` is painful to use for a task like this, and there's a much better, less well-known tool called [The BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), *specifically designed* for removing **Large Files** from Git repos.

The core command to remove big files looks just like this:

```
$ bfg  --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10MB  my-repo.git
```

Any blob over 10MB in size (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be *totally removed* from your repository's history - you don't have to manually find the files yourself, and files in protected commits are [safe](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits).

You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is typically [hundreds of times faster](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#speed) than running `git-filter-branch` on a big repo and the options are tailored around these two common use-cases:

- Removing **Crazy Big Files**
- Removing **Passwords, Credentials** & other **Private data**

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Maybe not equal but at least similar and a bit more official (see man page) than `--prune=now` is `--prune=all` (git 1.9.1)

Answer (score 3):

You need to run [David Underhill's](http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/) script on each branch in the repository to ensure the references are removed from all branches.

Then, as in the further discussion, initialize a new repository with `git init` and either  `git pull` from the original or `git remote add origin <original>` and then pull all branches.

```
$ du -sh ./BIG
299M ./BIG
$ cd BIG
$ git checkout master
$ git-remove-history REMOVE_ME
....
$ git checkout branch2
$ git-remove-history REMOVE_ME
...
$ cd ../SMALL
$ git init
$ git remote add origin ../BIG
$ git fetch --all
$ git checkout master
$ cd ..
$ du -sh ./SMALL ./BIG
26M ./SMALL
244M ./BIG
```

Answer (score 1):

I had accidentally stored large `.jpa` backups of my site in git -

`git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch MY_BIG_DIRECTORY_OR_FILE' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

Relpace `MY_BIG_DIRECTORY_OR_FILE` with the folder in question to completely rewrite your history, including tags.

source:

> http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history