# How might one push a different git history to different repositories?

Tags: git, github

TL;DR: **Is there an effective way to push “from now on, only” to a git repository mirroring another, without losing the history on other mirrors of the same project?**

I have a project of a certain scale (that is to say, “fat”) that is being pushed to three different repositories; one internal to a group “sponsoring” the project, one being Sourceforge, and one being GitHub.

Unfortunately, before this project “went public” to GitHub, some large AI “knowledgebase” type data files were added to the repository as CSV files; several over GitHub's size limit (soft limit 50MiB, hard limit 100MiB)

Once we realised the size issues, I've removed the files and pushed BZ2 files that the Makefile will (once I get around to doing it right) expand back out during the build process, when the files are compiled into the system's state.

Now, the internal repository and the Sourceforge are in sync, but even though the files are absent in the HEAD, I cannot push to GitHub.

Short of wiping out the .git control files (argh, and there are submodules! What a pain to set up properly again…) and starting over, is there a way to so something like

```
  git push origin BRANCH
  git push sourceforge BRANCH
  git push github from-xyzzy-to-HEAD:BRANCH
```

My best guess was to use

```
  git push github 320ce5..HEAD:BRANCH
```

but I get
      error: src refspec 320ce5..HEAD does not match any.
      error: failed to push some refs to …

(Note: 320ce5 is the latest commit, the one with the offending CSV files removed. So it's presumable = HEAD. I also tried adding a useless empty file and then removing it to “fake” some history in case that was the issue, but it didn't help.)

I'm starting to believe that the answer is “no,” and I should just archive the prior repository state, bite the bullet, and start over, which really shouldn't hurt anyone's feelings too much, but it is an hassle.

Comment: you can remove commits with big files from repository and push new version to github with `-f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not direct answer, but maybe useful for you. Drop big files from repo without cutting whole history with [BFG](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

```
bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M --replace-text banned.txt repo.git
```

clean repository

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

and push changed repo to repository with

```
git push --force --all
```

This is also possible to achieve this with [git-filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

Related questions:

- [Update a development team with rewritten Git repo history, removing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444091/update-a-development-team-with-rewritten-git-repo-history-removing-big-files)
- [Git repo still huge after large files removed from repository history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884331/git-repo-still-huge-after-large-files-removed-from-repository-history)

Comment: I ended up having to do something quite like this.