# Delete file on git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, rm

I uploaded a file(a huge fool file) accidentally to my git repository, when I noticed it I "removed" using `git rm the_fool_file`

Then I saw that the file is still at the repository althought it was removed from my local.

How can I removed from the server and definitely delete it?

Thanks in advance.

I also tried

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f myfile' HEAD
```

got

```
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

file is not at head, it was removed

Comment: Are you asking how to push the commit that removes the file, or how to destroy history?

Comment: So, try the search box in the upper right. The answer's already on SO, just look around a bit.

Comment: @SLaks I want to remove it from history

Comment: @DonBranson I have looked for answer but I haven't got it, so I asking for others opcions. For example when I tried `git rm --cached my_file` I get `fatal: pathspec 'myfile' did not match any files`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=github+remove+file+from+history

Comment: You deleted the file server doesn't know that. Just commit & push it...

Comment: @Learath2 I did it, so if you clone it you aren't going to download the file, but it is still at repository history

Comment: Only way to actually purge it from the history is filter-branch i think.

Comment: @Learath2 How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to purge it from history? Does it contain sensitive data?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data I love linking this page as it explains it quite well.

Comment: @DonBranson I want to remove it because it is huge and does not belong to the project, it was uploaded accidentally

Answer (score 3):

The [OP Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437986/andres) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912979/delete-file-on-git-repository#comment33204432_21912979):

> I want to remove it because it is huge and does not belong to the project, it was uploaded accidentally

Then the easiest way to do that is by using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

> Remove all blobs bigger than 1 megabyte :

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 1M  my-repo.git
```

That will take care of all the commits *before* the current one.

But don't forget to then run:

```
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

(as detailed in "[Git repo still huge after large files removed from repository history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176071/6309)")