# Drop old commit: `git rebase` causes merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge

Unfortunately we accidently checked in a large binary file some time ago and until today nobody noticed. Now I want to drop that commit and have the remaining history as it is. I know about the caveats of changing pushed history but in this case I cannot avoid it.

I have been trying to achieve that for ~1h but fail to get it. The best command I found is

```
git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges $(EVIL_COMMIT)^
```

and in the editor commenting out the 1st commit which is the evil one.

Unfortunately `git rebase` stops at merges and prompts for manual resolution of merge conflicts. The evil commit only adds some example files our software shall compute for testing purposes. Thus their shouldn't be any conflict with the example files just missing.

1. I do not understand where the merge conflicts originate from. Somebody can explain?
2. How to resolve that?

I've spent quite a lot of time at Google and SO search. Some threads cover a similar topic but either [syntax used is not available](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/1/31/237305) in today's Git version anymore or it didn't work for me (I only described one method above because it's the easiest approach).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with `filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter '
  git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/file
' --all
```

Comment: This does only remove the file `path/to/file` from all revisions, right? As far as I  understand it doesn't remove the commit which will be left empty after deleting the binaries (there are actually 4 of them).

Comment: I think you mean `HEAD` rather than `$(EVIL_COMMIT)^` in this answer - otherwise it would only filter the commits up to the one before the one that introduced the large file.

Comment: The option for `git rm` is `--ignore-unmatch` without *~ed*.

Comment: I successfully removed the commit introducing the binaries from my repo with `git filter-branch --index-filter '
  git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch --prune-empty file{A,B,C,D}
' HEAD`. I did that for all branches including the ones on upstream. Unfortunately `git prune` does not remove the objects but I cannot find any references to the files. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1/460417#460417 but it doesn't  list any commits containing the binaries. :-/

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! @halo: you'd have to expire the reflogs and remove the `refs/original` ref namespace (kept by git for safety reasons)

Comment: Finally got it by following http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html#removing_objects The large blob was still referenced by commits in the logs...

Comment: Will this also make the clone smalle

Answer (score 0):

My friend started a convenient script for purging files from git history, check https://github.com/donquixote/gitpurge