# How can I remove a binary from history?

Tags: git

I found out that it wasn't such a good idea to keep tracking the binary. The size of our repository is growing at a much faster rate than I would like. Is it possible to purge this file from git?

No one even needs to know it existed.

Comment: @svick you're right. Is there something I can do? Should I delete the post?

Comment: That's up to you. You can delete this question if you think it won't be useful to anyone. Or you can let others close it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history) and [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-do-i-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-in-git-history).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these fine questions and their answers, which explain how to use git filter-branch to do what you want to do:

- [Drop old commit: `git rebase` causes merge conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969831/drop-old-commit-git-rebase-causes-merge-conflicts)
- [Update a development team with rewritten Git repo history, removing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444091/git-filter-branch-to-delete-large-file)

For storing new big files in the future, I'd recommend using [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out to me and mentioning git-annex. I'll try that out

Comment: I've never heard of git-annex. Nowadays git LFS is used instead

Answer (score 3):

Theres a tool called BFG especially made for this task.

it has the advantage that sha1's referenced in commit messages will be updated too!

- http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner - main page.
- http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2013/04/gitminutes-06-roberto-tyley-on.html - interview with the author.

While being written in scala its easy to setup and run as a command line program.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `git filter-branch` to rewrite the repository.  You'll need to synchronize it across all users though and have a stop/restart day.

Comment: Recently it's recommended to use `git filter-repo`