# Git applying patches

Tags: linux, git, version-control

I have been working on a project which is maintained in git. I got a bunch of patches from someone who had previous worked on it. But he does not remember what version of source code he worked on. (Or if he had branched the repo before starting his work). 
When I tried to apply patches,some of them are failing. Some are not. Is there any way to figure out the branch/index on top which he created his first patch. 
(P.S.: The patches are numbered in order.)

(I assume patches cant be applied if you dont know the base version from which they were created. So, the patches what I have are kind of useless unless I dig through stuff.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open the diff file in a text editor.  At the top of the section for each file will be a header like the one shown below:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index d68fdef..f9aca24 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -1,3 +1,8 @@
+
...
```

The 'index' line includes the SHA-1 checksum of that file before and after the change.  You can use that to verify that a particular version of the file was used as the source for that diff.  There is [an answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460331/git-finding-a-filename-from-a-sha1) that includes an example script for searching through the repository history to find a file based on the SHA1.