# git find dependency on large object

Tags: git

I've tried to do a filter-branch like this to get rid of some large files:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter "git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch largedir*" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

However, I see that the large objects are still in my repository in the 'objects' directory, even after a new clone.
Is there a way to find out why these objects are still required according to git?

Comment: Remember that `filter-branch` *keeps all the old commits* under the `refs/original/` name-space (while making all-new commits and putting those in the ordinary `refs/heads/` name-space).  You must remove those, clean out reflogs, and `gc` to actually shrink the repository.  Also if you have tags you must make sure they get updated.  Though if you're cloning, the `refs/original/` name-space is not normally copied (and reflogs are never copied), but tags are.  (If you clone with `--mirror` all refs are copied!)

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/460331/1256452 -- find a large object's hash and use the above answer to see where it's referenced.