# Knowing the file that a number represents

Tags: git, github

When pushing commits I read this warning:

```
remote: warning: File cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226 is 63.25 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

But I don't know what is the file that this number points to.

I've tried https://github.com/iluaepidi/widget/blob/cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226 but with no sucess.

How can I know what file it is?

(note: I've tried `find -size` and didn't work)

Comment: What are you storing that's that big? Git isn't meant for such large files unless you're using Git LFS, which costs extra on Github. Sounds like a binary artifact from a build system, which you should be `.gitignore`-ing.

Comment: Indeed another warning says: `Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage`. My problem is that I can't ignore a file whose name I don't know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/460415/510036) you can try

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226
```

There is no direct mapping of filenames => object SHAs in Git, because multiple trees (and thus multiple commits) can refer to the same object in multiple places. The above command will show you all filenames that point to that object. If you get no results, you can probably assume it's either a tree or a commit, or it's unused.

Two commands to check that are to see what type it is:

```
git cat-file -t cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226
```

and if it specifies either `tree` or `commit`, then something is probably very much corrupt. Otherwise, if it specified either `blob` or errors out, you can probably just garbage-collect your repository to get rid of it.

```
git gc --prune
```

If that *still* doesn't work, and you don't mind running the risk of corrupting your repository (make a backup!) then you can manually delete the object.

Objects are stored in a lookup hierarchy, which means in `.git/objects` there are directories that correspond to the first byte of the object's SHA in hexadecimal format, and the contents of the directory being the object files named by their SHAs *sans* the first byte.

So in your case, you'll be removing the following:

```
rm .git/objects/cb/bf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226
```

Though if you're to this point, it's *highly* indicative that something else is wrong.

---

If you determine the offending object is a file, and the file is somewhere rooted in the history, you might be in for a revert, or worse, a little bit of a nasty rebase.

You'll have to find the commit that introduced the file, and then run **one** of the following commands:

- If the file was introduced by itself in its own commit:

  ```
  git revert <COMMIT>
  ```
- If the file was introduced alongside other changes, find the commit *before* the offending commit:

  ```
  git rebase -i <PRIOR COMMIT>
  ```

  Then navigate to the line with the offending commit and replace `pick` with `edit`, then write (save) and quit the editor. Git will then go into rebase mode and will check out that particular commit, at which point you can remove the offending file.

  After you've removed it, run the following:

  ```
  git add -A
  git commit --amend
  git rebase --continue
  ```

  If Git finishes with success, you're good to go. Otherwise, you might have to edit a few commits in-between the initial introduction of the file and HEAD in order to remove the file from all commits that modify that file.

Comment: wow thanks for your comprehensive response. I will start working on that just now. But just to clarify, I don't receive any warning when commiting but when pushing

Comment: @malarres Correct; you wouldn't. Git doesn't *care* about the size, but it's still built for smaller size objects. :) Github is the one enforcing that dogma.

Comment: The very first command did the trick! Thanks a lot. Note for the curious: `$ git rev-list --objects --all | grep cbbf81`
`cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226 node_modules/gpii-test-browser/node_modules/nightmare/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.
app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Electron Framework`

Comment: Yep - add `node_modules/` to your .gitignore file in the root of your repository. That should be the first thing you do in node.js repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up! You're being really helpful :) However I already had `$ cat .gitignore` with the line `node_modules` previously. Now that you pointed to that I've googled and found https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ so maybe I've had to do a `git rm --cached ` *before* having the push done

Comment: Either should work, though I prefer `node_modules/` to only include directories. `git rm -rf --cached **/node_modules/` should work as well.

Comment: Mystery solved: The push involved quite an ammount of commits, one of them had node_modules not ignored, a later commit solved that. So for the next time I will not skip the git rm --cached  ;) Thanks again for your help it has been really instructive

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `git show <sha>` to have git show you the file?

You could also do a `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep <sha>`

Comment: Thanks. `git show cbbf81da77a68297dcb6870025c5bb661c63e226` returns a binary file (that's my guess from the tangled output i read in console) with some text such as /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore^ that I think is something mac-related but couldn't say. The ls-tree returns an empty string. So far I couldn't get the name of the file but thanks to you I can at least start searching what the QuartzCore is