# Is "blob" a synonym for the contents of a file I put in a git repository?

Tags: git

A knowledgeable person who answered one of my more complicated git questions seemed to have the interpretation in this question's title, which I disagree with, so this is a misunderstanding that can even afflict expert git users.

I'll be offering my own understanding as an answer - which I'm happy for you to improve or approve (or both!) - but feel free to add well-supported answers that differ significantly from my interpretation.

Comment: The main problem here is context: in Git, "blob" is an *object type*, one of four such, for objects stored within the repository (in `.git/objects/` or a "pack file"). The name comes from the database world, where "blob" is an acronym (or perhaps retronym) for Binary Large OBject.

Comment: You gave an excellent answer to your own question.  I would encourage you to "accept" it.

Answer (score 3):

No, though conflicting usages of the term are easy to find, in some important ways, "blob" is not a synonym for the contents of a file that has been placed in a git repository.

For one, a blob object contains (sequentially):

- the word "blob"
- one space
- a null-terminated string representing the number of bytes in your file
- the actual (verbatim) data from your file

If your file data was the blob, then this definition of a blob's contents would be recursive.

Secondly, git stores the hash of the blob, not the hash of your file.  From the [**git(1)**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#Discussion) man page:

> All objects are named by the SHA-1 hash of their contents, normally written as a string of 40 hex digits

If the blob object and your file were the same thing, they would have the same hash.  They do not:

```
$ printf "a" > file
$ openssl sha1 file
SHA1(file)= 86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8
$ git hash-object file
2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e
$ printf "blob %d\000$(cat file)" $(wc -c file | awk '{print $1}') > file-blob
$ openssl sha1 file-blob
SHA1(file-blob)= 2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e
```

As you can see, the SHA1 of `file-blob`, constructed according to the above definition of a blob's contents, matches the hash that git stores to represent `file`, which we obtained from [**git-hash-object(1)**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-hash-object.html).

A third, maybe more pedantic, reason is because treating the blob as a synonym can be misleading to those who know "blob" from other contexts, such as databases, where a "BLOB" (Binary Large OBject) might be a verbatim representation of what you're storing.

To conclude: Although many people use "blob" as a sort of stand-in for the contents of a file in a repository, in git's parlance, it is not the same thing.  Although the blob object represents your file and contains its data (after an ASCII header string), any resemblance is purely coincidental.

Comment: What you're basically saying is that a blob is the contents of your file. It's one representation of the content but nonetheless is the content, not some other derived data. This is like asking is `0x0a` the number ten? In one respect, no, because first of all it starts with `0x` whereas numbers don't generally start with "oh-ex". In another more important way, yes, it's just another representation of ten. I've seen long heated flamewars in my life on weather or not computers actually process numbers or just a model of numbers. The distinction is really only useful for implementers

Comment: @slebetman What I said is that a git blob is **not** the contents of your file:  It's a little bit more and a little bit different than that.  While there certainly are times when the difference is effectively nil, it isn't hard to find rubbish comments made on SO for lack of awareness, or reacting as if this insight was false.

Comment: @slebetman Incidentally, your "number ten" statement could serve as an example of how ignoring context leads to needless strife: Not only does it help to know that hexadecimal numbers often start with `0x`, the purpose of those characters is, in fact, to identify the number base at times when the distinction is relevant and isn't clear from context.

Comment: To reitterate my PoV: the format of the object store of a Git repository is an implementation detail for you, the user of such repository. There's no way to store the contents of a file in a Git repository other than making a Git blob out of it (via `git hash-object -w <filename>`), and no way to fetch that contents back other than extracting it from that blob (via `git cat-file blob <sha1>`). IOW, you have to use Git for to do that. So even if Git would actually store the contents of your file being `base64`-encoded, that would merely be an irrelevant implementation detail.

Comment: Git devs are even free to change the format of how any object is stored at any time in the future (provided the implementation will be compatible with old formats). Or they may implement pluggable object storage backends (there are already patches floating around which implement this for the storage of refs). Oh, and the term "blob" used in this context is certainly not invented by me--please see `git help glossary`.

Comment: To explain my PoV in other words: when the contents of your file transitions from the file system (or other medium) into a Git repository it becames a Git blob. When it transitions back--from a blob into an actual file or a data stream directed somewhere--the blob becames the content of your file. Hence I state that since you have to use Git itself to perform both kinds of transitions, for any practical purpose (i.e. discussing locating a particular file in a repository by the contents of that file) we can safely use the term "blob" to refer to that contents.

Comment: Going 100% precise in terminology is useful for the purposes of (self-)education but then it only burdens the discussion because the distinction between stored blobs and the contents of the files does only matter when we explicitly talk about those transitions I referred to above. And actually where should we draw the line? Your filesystem is free to spread the contents of your file across the underlying physical medium block-wise in weird ways, and still makes sure you *perceive* your file as a single piece ;-)

Comment: @kostix I agree that the details of a blob object are not to be depended upon, and in practice it should be accessed only through documented interfaces.