# Find out the SHA1 of a file from the index

Tags: java, git, jgit

**Short story:**

Like the title says, how to get the SHA1 or hash from the index of a checked out file using JGit?

**Long story:**

I am writing an GUI application and using JGit for revisioning of just one file. So a user is able to open a window which contains all of the revisions of this file in a nice table.

User can make his changes and commit them. Also, user can go back in time and choose an older revision from a table to work on.

This workflow is very simple. What I internally do with JGit is that I use only one branch (the master branch). The HEAD is always pointing to this branch and the tip of this branch is always the newest commit. When a user chooses an older revision I simply instantiate `CheckoutCommand` class, set path to file using `addPath()` and use the branch *master* using `setName()`.

The above results in HEAD pointing to master branch which in turn points to the newest revision (not the user chosen revision). But the index and the working directory itself are now at the revision chosen by the user.

So, finally, I want to be able to present to user which of those revisions in table is currently checked out or activated or whatever you want to call this. This revision would than be highlighted like on the below screenshot. But i cannot use the tip of the master branch for this purpose. I need to somehow get the SHA1 from the index.

There is a question [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index) which is the exactly what I want but in the context of JGit (the author of the question uses git).

[image: Table representing versions]

**EDIT:** After just a little bit more analyzing I found that I could use JGit `DirCache` to access the contents of the index. So using `DirCache` class I am able to get the SHA1 of the file in the index just like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index). But now I see that this hash is not the same as the revision hash from which I checked out. Meaning, I can not use this method to determine which revision from a table is checked out.

So, is there any other way using my workflow described as is to determine which of the revisions is user chosen to work on? Or even, maybe someone can propose a different approach.

My current approach for this problem is to use JGit `AddNoteCommand`. When user checks out the revision I will simply add a note to this revision with some "key: value". This key will indicate if the revision is checked out or not. Anyone with a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

so first of all, sorry to say that, but I think it's dangerous and unintuitive to do what you do. Git is built so that you use branches. I think what you do is called Detached-head manipulation and it's not recommended, even though JGit allows you to do many things.
But if you are very careful well you can go on.

Second the Dircache (previously Index) object has been very mysterious to me and I think (I am not too sure though) the JGit team is still working on it.

Finally, to actually answer the question: I think you should use the LogCommand, with its addPath(...) method. You will get a list of RevCommit, from which you can determine the SHA1. I don't precisely remember how you get the SHA1, I think you should call getName() when you have a Ref object. I guess you'll find it on StackOverflow.

However, I would recommend to use branches (depending on what operation you want to perform on your commit), based on the SHA1 you got: you create a branch from the SHA1 you just found and can perform safely any operation you want. Then, either you destroy the branch if you don't want to commit anything or you will merge it later.