# Why does 'git ls-files -s' and 'git log' output a different SHA hash?

Tags: git, hash, sha

When using 'git ls-files -s' and 'git log' on the same file, I get different SHA hashes. Take the file lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim in repo https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree, tag 6.10.5, for example.

The command `git log lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim` produces,

`commit 593c16add35a5461f189b8189abe219f7bbbd604 (tag: 6.10.5)`

But the command `git ls-files -s lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim` produces,

`100644 61a11a96ba44c7b1bf0472b598f2c967b2dce9f2 0      lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim`

If I attempt to checkout the SHA returned by 'git log', that command succeeds. If I attempt to checkout the SHA returned by 'git ls-files -s', that produces a fatal error:

`git checkout 61a11a96ba44c7b1bf0472b598f2c967b2dce9f2 lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim`

`fatal: reference is not a tree: 61a11a96ba44c7b1bf0472b598f2c967b2dce9f2`

Why does 'git ls-files -s' and 'git log' produce different SHA hashes for the same file?

NOTE: I searched around for an answer and found this thread: [Git - finding the SHA1 of an individual file in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460297/git-finding-the-sha1-of-an-individual-file-in-the-index). This thread explains why there might be differences between the output of 'git hash-object' and 'git ls-files -s', but it does not explain the difference between the output of 'git ls-files -s' and 'git log'.

Comment: Read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain for more information about the various objects that exist in a Git repository and how they are used to implement a source control system.

Comment: @chepner I didn't realize that there are file objects and commit objects in GIT. This helped me: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: Sorry, that's the link I really meant to send. I didn't look at the table of contents closely enough to see there was a separate link to that section of chapter 10. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is:

1. The hash returned by `git log` is the hash which identifies the **commit**.
2. The hash returned by `git ls-files -s` is the identifier of the **file blob**.

Answer (score 2):

`git log` with a path lists *commits that change what's recorded at that path*.

`git ls-files` with a path lists *what's recorded in your current checkout at that path*.